# Native libraries are working in normal Java application but not in Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

For my application I need a third party framework. This framework consists of 2 Jar Files and 2 native libraries.

For testing purpose I added the files to a folder that is in my java library path. Now if I start my normal application, all works as expected.

But if I start my Eclipse plugin, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/java/libPQOSUtil.dylib:  no suitable image found.  Did find:  /usr/lib/java/libPQOSUtil.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1827)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1750)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
    at PQSDKMultiTouch.PQOSUtil.<clinit>(PQOSUtil.java:7)
    at PQSDKMultiTouch.PQMTClient.SendRequest(PQMTClient.java:61)
    ....
```

I didn't change anything. So what's the problem and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Your library has the wrong architecture (as the message says) probably referring to 32 VS 64 bits.

My guess is that eclipse is using it's internal java, which is perhaps 64 bits, and your installed jdk is 32bits (or the other way around). The libraries are one or the other, and only work with one of the ways.

Again, that's my guess, but probably worth checking!

Comment: I assumed the same, but I'm not sure why it works when using it in a normal java application, but not in a eclipse plugin.

Comment: Ok, I see. Well, like I said, Eclipse can use it's own internal JRE, so perhaps that's it. Check out [how eclipse finds the JVM](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F)